# Does the 128 Bus travel near Alexanderplatz and Kurt-Schumacher Platz in Berlin?

Tags: public-transport, germany, berlin

I need travel information from Alexanderplatz to October Fest @ Kurt-Schumacher-Platz arriving on Sept 30 2013 to October 1 2013.

Does Bus 128 travel near the above locations?

Comment: In Berlin? Why not take the U-Bahn?

Comment: The route of that specific line can be found here: http://www.bvg.de/index.php/de/binaries/asset/download/22204/file/1-1
It does pass by Kurt-Schumacher-Platz, but doesn't go as far as Alexanderplatz. You should probably take the U-Bahn, but just plan your route on the website.

Comment: If you're coming from the airport, then the [TXL Bus](http://www.bvg.de/index.php/de/binaries/asset/download/21259/file/1-1) does go to Alexanderplatz, but you're often better off doing bus+s-bahn or bus+u-bahn for that route as it's normally quicker than the bus the whole way!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you plan your route with the BVG (http://www.fahrinfo-berlin.de/Fahrinfo/bin/query.bin/en), they run most of the public transportation system of Berlin.

Comment: The route planner does not only work for BVG transportation, but also include e.g. S-Bahn. So yes, that's the right place to check for connections.